# Getting address of system()

Tags: python

I need help calculating system address. Normally, through GDB, you just open the program and type "p system" and there it pops. When done without gdb, this gets a little tricky.

You have to start the program and then immediately pause it, then looks in /proc/$pid/maps and get the address of the library. Then find the offset of system() in libc.so.6 and add these two together.

./test & kill -19 %1 seems to do the trick. When done manually, this thing works well, but when I get to doing this with python I run into some problems.

```
os.system("./test & kill -19 %1")
```

It then returns

```
sh: 1: kill: No such process
```

Why isn't it working? Is there possibly a better way to calculate system() address?

I need a python script that will run a program 'test' and pause it so that I can read /proc/$pid/maps

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I need a python script that will run a program 'test' and pause it so that I can read /proc/$pid/maps.

Comment: Does `/bin/sh -c './test & kill -19 %1'` work for you? I think that's more-or-less what your code is doing.

Comment: I need to do this through python and that code doesn't work when implemented through python. A python script that runs that returns "/bin/sh: 1: kill: No such process"

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that `%1`, belonging to the job control facilities of the shell, doesn't work within a non-login shell.

But there are other ways:

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.popen(["./test"])
sp.send_signal(19)
with open("/proc/%d/maps" % sp.pid, "rb") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

will start the subprocess and then immediately send it a signal.
After that, it gets its `maps` file.